# Cannot SSH into ANY host (outgoing) on entire local network

Tags: ssh, timeout, ports

I'm having a rather strange issue with my network here, and I'm hoping you guys might be able to help me out.

As of recently, over the past few weeks or so, I've been noticing some strange problems with connecting via SSH to things like my VPS in the Terminal or with Git repos, etc.  It seems that they weren't always making the connection, eventually timing out...

I just restarted my router moments ago, and I was able to connect for a few seconds to my VPS, now it's timing out again.

Is it the router that's having the issues?  Or is it something else?  I haven't had this issue until recently, and it got worse and worse over time.  I'm able to SSH within my network, I can SSH to my laptop from my iPod touch for example, outside of the network seems to not work.

If I use a VPN or a proxy even, I can SSH into anything I want, but without it fails.

Does anyone know the source of the problem and what I should do to fix it?  One minute I think it's my ISP, and the next my router...

Comment: I just reset the router again, and it didn't help at all... so it would seem it was just a coincidence?

Comment: Remove the router and connect your computer directly to test whether it's a router issue...

Comment: I would be suspicious of the ISP. Do you have a cable provider such as Road Runner? I've had intermittent problems in the past where it turned out to be a cabling issue with my ISP. The problem would usually present as coming and going similar to what you're subscribing.

Comment: @slm I have Road Runner actually, yes.  Things seem to be stable right now, I ended up mucking with the ports on my VPS to see if that would change anything and messed up when I put them back.

Comment: @jjlin I can't check right now, when I have the problem again long term I can try that.  I know, I should have done this before, most things in my house are mainly using the WiFi, I only have one device that can really even check now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure port 22 outbound is open? Try properly forwarding 22 to your computer's IP in the router config.

Comment: That isn't the issue, I wouldn't be able to do that for my entire network.